# Unknown in 'on clause' when adding left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this query working:

```
SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
        posts.id as id
FROM posts,familias,textos
WHERE
    lower(titulo) LIKE 'my title' 
    AND posts.id_familia = familias.id $familiaQuery
    AND familias.clave = textos.clave 
    AND textos.lengua = 1
GROUP by posts.id
ORDER by count(*) desc
```

But I wanted to add the tags search

```
SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
        posts.id as id
FROM posts,familias,textos
    LEFT JOIN tags_map ON tags_map.id_post = posts.id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags_map.id_ing = tags.id
WHERE
    tags.nombre LIKE 'php'
    AND lower(titulo) LIKE 'my title' 
    AND posts.id_familia = familias.id $familiaQuery
    AND familias.clave = textos.clave 
    AND textos.lengua = 1
GROUP by posts.id
ORDER by count(*) desc
```

But then I get this error `Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'on clause'` which I don't understand, the field has been there all along.

Why it can't find it?

Comment: Don't use commas in the from clause

Comment: How should I select from multiple tables, then?

Comment: same using joins only.

Comment: But why is it working in the first query?

Comment: Commas and joins do/are the same thing, but commas are evaluated in a different order from joins, meaning that the table that you think you're joining to is still outside the internal scope of the query

Comment: It's about scopes. In an explicit JOIN chain, only columns from already mentioned tables can be used.

Comment: I very much apreciate the explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only Join``s in your from `clause` no comma

```
SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
        posts.id as id
FROM posts
    JOIN familias ON posts.id_familia = familias.id  
    JOIN textos ON familias.clave = textos.clave 
    LEFT JOIN tags_map ON tags_map.id_receta = posts.id
    LEFT JOIN tags ON tags_map.id_ing = tags.id
WHERE
    tags.nombre LIKE 'php'
    AND lower(titulo) LIKE 'my title' 
    $familiaQuery
    AND textos.lengua = 1
GROUP by posts.id
ORDER by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Not exactly the same. Joins chains are evaluated before comma separated tables. I.e. posts JOIN familias JOIN  (textos LEFT JOIN etc ...)

Comment: @jarlh . . . I'm pretty sure this is what the OP intends (the OP is essentially asking to put left joins on an existing query).  It is true that this isn't exactly the same as the proposed query, but it doesn't work and the OP is unlikely to understand the nuances of join ordering.

Comment: But note that `LEFT JOIN tags WHERE tags` = `INNER JOIN tags`. Also, I'm pretty sure that even where a case-sensitive collation is used, LIKE ignores the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could be mixing up syntaxes.

I think you could wrap your query up in a subquery in case you want to keep it:

```
 SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT  posts.titulo as value,
         posts.id as id
  FROM posts,familias,textos
     AND lower(titulo) LIKE 'my title' 
     AND posts.id_familia = familias.id $familiaQuery
     AND familias.clave = textos.clave 
     AND textos.lengua = 1
 )
LEFT JOIN tags_map ON tags_map.id_receta = posts.id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags_map.id_ing = tags.id
WHERE
    tags.nombre LIKE 'php'
GROUP by posts.id
ORDER by count(*) desc
```

Comment: Note that "WHERE tags.nombre LIKE 'php'" makes that LEFT JOIN execute as a regular INNER JOIN. Move condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN behavior!